# Curl как получить данные с твиттера?

Tags: curl, twitter

Есть ссылка например:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=1111

Есть код:

```
$ch = curl_init($url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);            $result = curl_exec($ch);           echo curl_error($ch);           curl_close($ch);
```

Но данные не возвращаются. По другим ссылкам проверила, проходит этот код. Если зайти на указанную ссылку вот такая ошибка:
    {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Как настроить авторизацию, чтоб не было проблем?

Comment: post, get параметры какие? Заголовки запроса?

Comment: @Barton q="любой текстовый запрос" и geocode=широта,долгота,радиус

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку получаете потому, что необходимо в заголовках отправить данные для авторизации.
Вот на stackoverflow есть пример:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1